# Java How to get scanner.nextLine() on the same line?

Tags: java

I have a program that takes input from the user from the command line.  Annoyingly the first time I use the scanner the inputted text goes on the next line (after the `System.out.println`).  However, all the other times it is on the same line as the `System.out.println`.

Code:

```
//Create a scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//Gets type
System.out.println("--Television Show or Film (t or f): ");
String type = input.nextLine();
input.close();
```

Output:

```
--Television Show or Film (t or f): 
t
```

Desierd Output:

```
--Television Show or Film (t or f): t
```

Any help is appreciated. Also, I'm using Eclipse Console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
   System.out.print("--Television Show or Film (t or f): ");
   String type = input.next();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `System.out.print` rather than `System.out.println` ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are using the `println` version of `System.out`. Use only `print`: `System.out.print("--Television Show or Film (t or f): ");`